# Moment.js - converting int numbers in array to hour:minute format

Tags: momentjs

Well, this is just a question rather than a coding problem.

Is it possible to convert integers in an array from [0-23] into momentjs's "HH:mm" format ??

Comment: An example please?

Comment: Hmmmmm,

Say i have an array of numbers

x = [0,1, 2, 3,......,22, 23]

And, what i want to output, is the hour:minute format using moment.js 

But since the array are nothing but numbers, you can't just 

console.log(moment(x).format("HH:mm")) 

right ?

Comment: What exactly are these numbers?

Comment: So, my point is that is there a way to convert those numbers in the array, to an hour:minute format with momentjs

Comment: @sv12 integer numbers

Comment: var numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24];
numbers.forEach(number => { 
        console.log(moment(number.toString(), "LT").format("HH:mm"))
});

Comment: Oh hey, i don't have to abuse moment.utc(). thanks

Comment: is that you were looking for?

Comment: For now, yes. i found a silimiar answer before asking this question using milliseconds with moment.utc(). but im did not expecting the "toString()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]; 
numbers.forEach(number => { console.log(moment(number.toString(), "LT").format("HH:mm")) });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```